# Controller parameter properties NULL when using jQuery POST Internet Explorer ONLY

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, internet-explorer, jquery

I have a jQuery post to a MVC controller. The call works fine in Firefox & Chrome but the objects properties are null when using IE?

Any idea what could be causing this for internet explorer

```
            var orderModel =
            {
                FirstName: this.address['name_first'],
                Surname: this.address['name_last'],
                Amount: this.finalTotal,
                Line1: this.address['line1'],
                Line2: this.address['line2'],
                City: this.address['city'],
                Code: this.address['code'],
                Region: this.address['region'],
                Country: this.address['country'],
                Shipping: shippingCost,
                Phone: this.address['phone'],
                EmailAddress: this.address['email_address'],
                OrderItems: items2
            };
        var form;
        $.ajaxSetup({ 'async': false });
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: this.url,
            data: JSON.stringify(orderModel),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                // Process result...
            }
        });

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddPurchaseDetails(OrderModel order)
    {
        //DO Something...
     }
```

Comment: are you sure about this line?
url: this.url

Comment: Does the post request look the same from IE compared with FF. Usually this type of problem appears because of content from data property of the $.ajax.

Comment: this.url contains the url to the contoller, it is being called but the properties of the object are null.